# How to get access to package in not rooted phone like Samsung

Tags: android, shell, permissions, export, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to export my database.db file but I have problem when I want to do that in Samsung phone (package in unknown it's going about permissions). I other rooted phone I'm using adb shell commands :

```
adb shell
run-as package name
chmod 777 databases
chmod 777 databases/databasename.db
exit
cp /data/data/packagename/databases/databasename.db /sdcard
exit
adb pull /sdcard/databasename.db
```

and it works. There is an option to change that permissions or an easy way  to get that file without writing function to export that file ?

Comment: You should make an Android app that copies the database file from internal memory to external memory or SD card.

Answer (score 0):

For unrooted phones, you can add **android:debuggable = true** in your Manifest file inside  the application tag.

Then you can use the similar commands to pull for you app.

`adb shell "run-as com.YOUAPP.app chmod 666 databases/DB.db"
adb shell "cp /data/data/com.YOURAPP.app/databases/DB.db /sdcard/"
adb shell "run-as com.YOURAPP.app chmod 600 databases/DB.db"
adb pull /sdcard/DB.db`

Comment: Tell me this line **android:debuggable = true** only set my device in debugable mode ? so if it is chacked at my phone and I use it to debug it means that this line is useless ?

Comment: Like I said this is useless because I can't run-as if for device package is unknown

Comment: No it sets your app in debug mode.
Why is device package unknown?